# External and internal Edge Detection for ideal image

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

I am looking for an algorithm that can do external and internal contour detection on an ideal image containing only two different RGB values.

Below is a typical example of the image (first one) I want to process, next image is one I made myself showing the result I am expecting.

The last one is a result from OpenCV Canny detection made through the demo software available at [OpenCV demo Software](http://www.tsdconseil.fr/log/opencv/demo/index-en.htmlhttp://).

The canny algorithm is not satisfying as it is smoothing too much the shapes (especially corner).

Are there any elegant algorithm that could give the same results as in the second image?

[image: Original Image]
[image: My own brain's contour detection and expected result]
[image: OpenCV -> Contour algorithm result]

Comment: use cv::threshold or different method to create the perfect mask, then use cv::findContours with appropriate flags to find external and internal contours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contour extraction is the easiest thing to do this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/ContourExtraction.png");

    cv::Mat mask;
    // create a perfect mask: Easy if you know the 2 colors present in your image:
    cv::inRange(input, cv::Scalar(100, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), mask);
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours; // contour points
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy; // this will give you the information whether it is an internal or external conotour.

    // contour extraction: This will alter the input image, so if you need it later use mask.clone() instead
    findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv::Point(0, 0)); // use different CV_CHAIN_APPROX_ if you dont need ALL the points but only the ones that dont lie on a common line

    // output images:
    cv::Mat contoursExternal = input.clone();
    cv::Mat contoursInternal = input.clone();
    cv::Mat contoursAll = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), CV_8UC1);

    // draw contours
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::drawContours(contoursAll, contours, i, cv::Scalar::all(255), 1);
        if (hierarchy[i][3] != -1) cv::drawContours(contoursInternal, contours, i, cv::Scalar::all(255), 1);
        else cv::drawContours(contoursExternal, contours, i, cv::Scalar::all(255), 1);
    }

    cv::imshow("internal", contoursInternal);
    cv::imshow("external", contoursExternal);
    cv::imshow("all", contoursAll);


    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

giving these results:

External contours:

[image]

Internal contours:

[image]

result mask:

[image]

Comment: I suppose that the "OpenCV demo" applies a Gaussian blur or something before Canny. That's why the edges are "smooth"

Comment: After few tests on different images, this algorithm gives very good results.

Answer (score 1):

One that gives a bit more jaggedness to the edges is the Roberts Cross Algorithm. Though it is very susceptible to noise in your example I don't believe it'll be a deal breaker.

There's a nice summary of how it works that explains it far better than myself [Here](http://www.robotics.technion.ac.il/courses/advanced_laboratory/lab7/arl_7_read.pdf). Essentially you take a 2x2 region, perform an x and y convolution and approximate the gradient magnitude because square roots are for slowpokes.